# "Hidden" function on object in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want function to be available on a object, but I don't it to be visible if if I console.log it or send it to another function.

```
var obj = function() {
  this.name = 'Bob';
  this.age = 23;
}
obj.prototype.say = function() {
  console.log(this.name, this.age, 'thats me..');
}

var pers = new obj();
console.log(pers); // { name: 'Bob', age: 23 } 
pers.say(); // Bob 23 thats me..
```

Would this be good for solution and good practice for that? Or is it a better way to accomplish this in javascript?

Comment: This doesn't make it invisible I think. Just click on the "prototype" tag if you're on chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functions created by using prototype would also be visible when you log the object. The only thing you can do at this context is to create functions in your constructor using `this` and create a `closure`. And these functions will not be a shared functions among the object instances unlike prototypal functions. I mean, the function's change will not be reflected in all object instances.

```
var obj = function() {
  this.name = 'Bob';
  this.age = 23;
  function privateTest(){ alert("hai"); }
  this.test = privateTest;
}
```

Comment: @NinaScholz But privateTest would not be visible. That is the point here.

Comment: When i logg your solution (I'm running node if that matter) I get: { name: 'Bob', age: 23, test: [Function: privateTest] }

Comment: @user3688556 That is fine. But you will not have control over `privateTest`